# Google Assistant working only my real device

Tags: android, kotlin, app-actions

I made a sample application for test google assistant. I uploaded my app into google play, downloaded it and it's working perfect on my phone. On the other hand I tried this app on other real devices and its not working. Application opening but I can't use app features.

My actions XML:

```xml
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?><!--  Learn More about how to use App Actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/index.html -->
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">

        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://trivias.page.link/open{?featureName}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="feature"
                urlParameter="featureName" />
        </fulfillment>
        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
        </parameter>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
        <entity
            name="Open cat facts"
            identifier="Open cat facts" />
        <entity
            name="Open dog facts"
            identifier="Open dog facts" />
        <entity
            name="Open bird facts"
            identifier="Open bird facts" />
        <entity
            name="Open general facts"
            identifier="Open general facts" />
        <entity
            name="Surprise me"
            identifier="Surprise me" />
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

My handler :

```
fun Intent.handleIntent() {
    when(action) {
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW  -> handleDeepLink(data)
        else -> gotoDefaultView()
    }
}
private fun gotoDefaultView() {

}
private fun handleDeepLink(data: Uri?) {
    when(data?.path) {
        "/open" -> {
            val featureType = data.getQueryParameter("featureName").orEmpty()
         
            useFeature(featureType)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you mean by "not working".  There should be enough information that anyone can use to duplicate the problem exactly as you observe it.  Be specific about the steps you are taking and what other devices you are using.